# Disable "install" message in NetBeans 12.0 when not use nb-javac

Tags: netbeans

I have a pretty good idea of the reasons nb-javac exists - but I don't use Compile on Save, and the presence of nb-javac suppresses the ability to use preview features.

It is of course, easy to uninstall. But what I cannot figure is once uninstalled how to avoid getting the warning message telling me to install it on every startup. Anyone figured this?

The rest of the IDE seems to work fine with it not present. It's just an annoyance always seeing that message.